# Unable to loop over a file using context manager python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, with-statement

```
instances = ['XYZ']
curr_date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    
    for inst_name in instances:
        with open(f'results_{inst_name}_master.csv') as f:
            pkt_name = f.readline().split(';')[1]
            print(f"package name is: {pkt_name}")
            run_dt = f.readline().split(';')[1]
            print(f"run date: {run_dt}")
            time_check = f.readlines()[1].split(';')[-5].split(':')[0]
            print(f"time is : {time_check}")
            if ((run_dt == curr_date) or (run_dt < curr_date and time_check in range(20,24))):
                for index, l in enumerate(f, 1):
                    if 'remoteInstallation' in l:
                        print(l)
```

Sample file:

```
pktName;sample-quality.zip;
RunDate;20220116;
sample:path_to_test\test;20220116;01:29:13;20220114;01:33:36;0:04:22;
;sample:path\to\remoteInstallation;45.99;../logs_path/index.html;OK;
;sample:path\to\remoteInstallation;42.87;../logs__other_path/index.html;1
```

I'm getting all the results except `print(l)`, that is , it's unable to loop over the file although the string : 'remoteInstallation' is present in the file.

Please note that in actual, the file contains the newline characters(\n) at the end of each line.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would certainly help to include example of a file.

Comment: @BijayRegmi : Added sample file...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using `readlines()` instead of `.readline()` on the time_check line.

```
import time
instances = ['XYZ']
curr_date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

for inst_name in instances:
    with open(f'results_{inst_name}_master.csv') as f:
        pkt_name = f.readline().split(';')[1]
        print(f"package name is: {pkt_name}")
        run_dt = f.readline().split(';')[1]
```

This line appears to be incorrect. It calls `readlines` and references the element at the first index. I removed the `s` and the index reference.

```
        time_check = f.readline().split(';')[-5].split(':')[0]  

        print(f"time is : {time_check}")
        if ((run_dt == curr_date) or (run_dt < curr_date and time_check in range(20,24))):
            for index, l in enumerate(f, 1):
                if 'remoteInstallation' in l:
                    print(l)
```

What happened behind the scenes?

For file objects (in this case `f`) there is an internal pointer that keeps track of where in the file the script is currently looking. This pointer is universal and used by multiple functions and by for loops.

Each call to `readline()` will read a line from the file and move the pointer to the next line.
Any call to `readlines()` will read all the lines until the end of the file and move the pointer to the end of the file.
For loops read the next line (if there is one) and keep repeating that process until the pointer is at the end of the file. In our code, this line:

```
for index, l in enumerate(f, 1):
```

is a for loop that is attempting to read more lines from the file.

Unfortunately, in our case, by calling `readlines()`, we have already read all the lines from file and have already moved the pointer to the end of the file and thus the for loop was unable to read in any new lines.

Comment: Thanks for the response, one query though: what if i wanted to read the 6th line to get the value of  `time_check`?

Comment: because the for loop, without any sort of stopping mechanism, will run to the end of the file, it may be necessary to include some tests to determine when to change behavior. This could be a test for which line you are on (using the index generated by enumerate OR a counter), whether the line has a specific string in it, etc. When the test condition is true, you can then have the code extract something different (ie the time). But we are now getting into a slightly higher level of complexity and nuance that is hard to answer in a simple comment.